# Postfix don't sign all mails with DKIM-Signature

Tags: email, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, postfix-mta, dkim

I have postfix and opendkim working on my server(Ubuntu 16.04), but postfix do not sign all mails with dkim.

If I send a mail from server with:

```
echo "test email" | sendmail check-auth@verifier.port25.com
```

I have a response that says `DKIM check: pass` because the mail has DKIM-Signature. I was trying send mails to my gmail account by this method and the mails has a DKIM-Signature too.

But when I try to send mails using Thunderbird or something similar the mails has no DKIM-Signature.

The server only has one domain and the next configurations:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**:

```
[...]
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

**/etc/opendkim.conf**:

```
[...]
SOCKET              inet:8891@localhost
UserID              opendkim
KeyTable            /etc/opendkim/key.table
SigningTable        refile:/etc/opendkim/signing.table
```

**/etc/opendkim/key.table**:

```
example.com example.com:default:/etc/dkimkeys/dkim.key
```

**/etc/opendkim/signing.table**:

```
*@example.com example.com
```

I was looking on `mail.log`, `mail.err` and `syslog` but I don't see anything related, neither errors.

I'm checking different configurations, I can send DKIM-signed mails form server with sendmail using different configurations but I still can't send mails signed with DKIM with Thunderbird... :(

Any Idea? Any place to look?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem.

In some sites they say that its necesary put the next line in `/etc/postfix/master.cf` for avoid problems:

```
-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters
```

But its wrong, that line makes the mails didn't signed.

In `/etc/postfix/master.cf` we can uncomment the next line to get working the port 587:

```
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```